# how would you prevent theft in a simple way other than a kill switch?

Tags: safety, security

I know you can get a kill switch for to prevent theft.

I’m a bit busy right now but I’m any case what is wrong with just removing a relay or switching a main fuse with a broken one? Might the constant adding and removing cause any damage or would this be a good ideA?

Any other ideas on how to prevent theft in an easy way?

Thanks

Comment: After reading many of your questions, i guess your car is safe.

Comment: @Johannes_B if it is the one with bumper damage, paint issues and oil leaks it may already be “safe”...

Comment: Let them steal it and break down about 2 miles away, that'll teach them.

Answer (score 2):

Having to open the bonnet or hood to remove / refit said fuse or relay is *so** obvious and time consuming same as grovelling under the dash for a fuse or relay there. May just as well remove a coil lead or the dizzy rotor arm which was done on older cars by some.

I put a kill switch on a Volvo 240 in the row of standard switches, in fact it was also a spare standard switch (from a scrappie) in plain sight - so easy to see but hard to work out the function.

Of course, a denver boot is a possible solution (wheelclamp), but a louisiana spanner is a solution to that...

Comment: What is a louisiana spanner?

Comment: @Martin a gas axe aka an oxy-actylene torch.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want something quick and simple, removing the starter relay or engine computer's  fuse/relay is generally enough. Just make sure to remove the ignition side fuse for pcm and not the keep alive memory fuse.
Cant imagine you would cause any damage other then maybe widening the terminals in the fuse box more then normal